# Filter data from Left table BEFORE a LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, outer-join

I have seen answers on filtering data from RIGHT table before a LEFT JOIN by putting the filter condition inside the ON clause. But haven't found an answer of filtering on the LEFT table before the JOIN.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1
    (col1 varchar(1), col2 varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO tbl1
    (col1, col2)
VALUES
    ('a', '1'),
    ('b', '1'),
    ('a', '2')
;


CREATE TABLE tbl2
(col1 varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO tbl2
    (col1)
VALUES
    ('a'),
    ('b')
;
```

This filters the data from the RIGHT table:

```
select tbl1.col1 tlc1, tbl1.col2 tlc2, tbl2.col1 t2c1
from
  tbl1
left join
 tbl2
on (tbl1.col1=tbl2.col1 and tbl1.col2=1)
```

But how do I achieve the filtering on the LEFT table similarly without doing a sub-query?

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xyoJDjHVQHYBdTxZFCRtJt/1

Comment: "filtering data from RIGHT table before a LEFT JOIN by putting the filter condition inside the ON clause" is unclear but also strange. "filters the data " is not clear--use enough words & sentences & references to parts of examples ot be clear. A [mcve] includes a clear specification & desired output. Also: Learn what LEFT/RIGHT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left/right table rows extended by NULLs. FULL JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left & right table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

Comment: You are not explaining what you want. You write unclear things about "filtering on/from" an outer join table & you don't give desired output. The only standard use of "filter" is to mean to use a WHERE. Stop using that word & say what you mean. "use enough words & sentences & references to parts of examples ot be clear" PS Have you read & understood my comment re what outer joins return? Do you understand that x left join y is just y right join x? What do you think is wrong with a subquery? Why do you mention them now since you edited yours out? Why & how would you use one? Not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You simply use a `where` clause:

```
select tbl1.col1 as tlc1, tbl1.col2 as tlc2, tbl2.col1 as t2c1
from tbl1 left join
     tbl2
     on tbl1.col1 = tbl2.col1 and tbl1.col2 = 1
where tbl1.col2 = 1;
```

To filter on the *right* table, you move the condition to the `on` clause:

```
select tbl1.col1 as tlc1, tbl1.col2 as tlc2, tbl2.col1 as t2c1
from tbl1 left join
     tbl2
     on tbl1.col1 = tbl2.col1 and tbl1.col2 = 1 and tbl2.col2 = ?;
```

Comment: To expand on what Gordon has said, WHERE is conceptually applied after a JOIN/FROM, but practically speaking most SQL implementations apply conditions in the WHERE early when it is safe to do so as a performance optimization.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have read in docs that WHERE clause is applied AFTER the join. And I want to make sure that the optimization is done before the JOIN.  I guess doing a sub-query is the only sure-shot way of doing that?

Comment: @figaro . . . `WHERE` clauses are *parsed* (i.e. "interpreted") after the `FROM` clause (and hence all `JOIN`s in it).  That is why the `WHERE` clause can refer to columns from any table.  How the SQL is *executed* though has little to do with the structure of the query itself.  The SQL engine (particularly the optimizer) chooses the best path.  If documentation suggested that `WHERE` is run *after* `FROM`/`JOIN`, then that documentation is incorrect or misleading.